# Why this command history i made doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am trying to create a js console and i want to do the console thing that when you press the uparrow it puts the last command you executed.
So i did this but idk why it doesnt work:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="author" content="MightyCoderX">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Online Js Console</title>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="general.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="input-container">
        <div class="prompt">></div>
        <input class="input">
    </div>
    <div class="output"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
var input;
var output;
var cmdHistory = [];

window.onload = function()
{
    input = document.querySelector(".input");
    output = document.querySelector(".output");

    input.onkeydown = function(e)
    {   
        var currentIndex;
        if(e.key == "Enter" && input.value)
        {
            var inputExp = document.createElement("p")
            inputExp.id = "inputExp";
            inputExp.innerHTML = "> " + input.value;
            cmdHistory.push(input.value);
            output.appendChild(inputExp);

            var result = document.createElement("p");

            result.id = "result";
            output.appendChild(result);
            try
            {
                result.innerHTML = "< " + eval(input.value);
            }
            catch(ex)
            {
                result.innerHTML = ex;
                result.style.color = "red";
            }

            var topPos = result.offsetTop;
            output.scrollTop = topPos;

            currentIndex = cmdHistory.length-1;
            console.log(currentIndex);
            input.value = "";
        }


        console.log("Out " + currentIndex);
        if(e.key == "ArrowUp")
        {
            if(currentIndex > -1)
            {
                console.log("In " + currentIndex);
                input.value = cmdHistory[currentIndex];

                currentIndex -= 1;
                console.log("After " + currentIndex);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Here is my code idk what is wrong i thought it was ok but apparently it doesnt work cause if i press the up arrow it shows this:
[Here it is my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXKHU.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move `var currentIndex` to outside of `window.onload`  function . and it may work for you.

```
var input;
var output;
var cmdHistory = [];
var currentIndex; 
window.onload = function()
{
    input = document.querySelector(".input");

    output = document.querySelector(".output");

    input.onkeydown = function(e)
    {   

        if(e.key == "Enter" && input.value)
        {
            var inputExp = document.createElement("p")
            inputExp.id = "inputExp";
            inputExp.innerHTML = "> " + input.value;
            cmdHistory.push(input.value);
            output.appendChild(inputExp);

            var result = document.createElement("p");

            result.id = "result";
            output.appendChild(result);
            try
            {
                result.innerHTML = "< " + eval(input.value);
            }
            catch(ex)
            {
                result.innerHTML = ex;
                result.style.color = "red";
            }

            var topPos = result.offsetTop;
            output.scrollTop = topPos;


            currentIndex = cmdHistory.length-1;
            console.log(currentIndex);
            input.value = "";
        }


        console.log("Out " + currentIndex);
        if(e.key == "ArrowUp")
        {
            if(currentIndex > -1)
            {
                console.log("In " + currentIndex);
                input.value = cmdHistory[currentIndex];

                currentIndex -= 1;
                console.log("After " + currentIndex);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
var currentIndex;
```

to

```
var currentIndex = cmdHistory.length -1;
```